# Is the impossibly fast delegate a suitable alternative to std::function?

Tags: c++, performance, delegates, compare

I recently came across an article called "The impossibly fast c++ delegates" and the c++11 version of it called "The impossibly fast c++ delegates fixed" which appear to be quite popular. It seems that they have the same use case than std::function, ie coercing different functor types into a single type. However, the authors claim that they are much more performant.

Are they a suitable, performant alternative to std::function? If so, why isn't std::function implemented the same way? Or are there any drawbacks to the impossibly fast c++ delegates?

EDIT:
As the comments have requested, the main idea of  "The impossibly fast c++ delegates" seems to be storing a pointer to untyped data alongside with a function pointer which takes the pointer to untyped data as an argument. "The impossibly fast c++ delegates fixed" extend the previous functionality to support lambdas among other things. Here is the code summary shown in the "The impossibly fast c++ delegates"

```
class delegate
{
public:
    delegate()
        : object_ptr(0)
        , stub_ptr(0)
    {}

    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)(int)>
    static delegate from_method(T* object_ptr)
    {
        delegate d;
        d.object_ptr = object_ptr;
        d.stub_ptr = &method_stub<T, TMethod>; // #1
        return d;
    }

    void operator()(int a1) const
    {
        return (*stub_ptr)(object_ptr, a1);
    }

private:
    typedef void (*stub_type)(void* object_ptr, int);

    void* object_ptr;
    stub_type stub_ptr;

    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)(int)>
    static void method_stub(void* object_ptr, int a1)
    {
        T* p = static_cast<T*>(object_ptr);
        return (p->*TMethod)(a1); // #2
    }
};
```

And here are the links for the two articles:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170503/The-Impossibly-Fast-Cplusplus-Delegates-Fixed

Comment: Show us the concept. Don't let us have to search what those implementations are.

Comment: *Are they a suitable, performant alternative to std::function?* This is really going to depend on the use case.  `std::function` is meant to be generic since it is a library type.  You loose some performance when you have to be very generic.  If your use case allows for a less generic approach, then you can probably squeeze some more performance out with you own solution.  The really trick is can you make a faster `std::function` that conforms to all the requirements that `std::function` has.

Comment: @NathanOliver How are the impossibly fast delegates less generic than std::function?

Comment: IDK.  You need to show it here.  I'm not going to go look for it.

Comment: Well, now that I see the code at least I can answer your question.  This delegate doesn't work with non member functions, so right there it is not a drop in replacement for `std::function`.

Comment: I am with Nathan, your question boils down to: Does the impossibly fast delegate meet the specification for `std::function`. That it is possible to write a function delegate for some specific use-case where it is more performant than `std::function` should not be a surprise. What matters is how `std::function` is specified, not only some aspects, but all of them. In case they made a design decision that makes their delegate different from `std::function` in any small detail, then it isnt `std::function`

Answer (score 2):

> are there any drawbacks to the impossibly fast c++ delegates?

Provided sample only handles:

- fixed signature `void(int)` (can easily be fixed with template)
- method pointer (with its class) (so no lambda/functor directly, no regular function pointer).

lambda/Functor can easily be adapted with their `operator()`.
Not sure about the possible overhead to handle function pointer.

Provided sample doesn't handle:

- **ownership**.

That is the main difference between both implementation, and that one add overhead (both at creation and execution compared to no-ownership)

Note: there are other ["function_view"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html)

> Are they a suitable, performant alternative to `std::function`?

If you don't need ownership, yes.

> If so, why isn't `std::function` implemented the same way?

As `std::function` should handle ownership.